# real time graph with matplotlib and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, matplotlib

I am currently scraping a website and trying to create a real-time graph from the information being scraped from the website using selenium and using matplotlib to create the graph. I can't seem to get the program to create the graph the program seems to be able to get the information from the website but the graph does not seem to be working can someone help. Below is the code

I’m order for the program to work the window open has to be a tennis match

```
ff = []

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt      
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style


style.use('fivethirtyeight')

   
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
 
    
driver.execute_script('window.open("https://livebetting.sportingbet.com/en/live#/8637814","_self")')
                                       
    
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[2]/div/lbk-scoreboard-common/div/div[1]/a/span')[0]
python_button.click()
    
statButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[2]/div/lbk-scoreboard-common/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[1]')[0]
statButton.click()
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


def animate(i):
    
    title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[3]')[0].text
    import time
    count = 0
    y = []
    x = []
    
    
    
    while title == driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[3]')[0].text:
        #while driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/lb-marketboard/div/div/div[1]')[0].text != 'We are sorry but no bets are available for this event.'
        try:
           # now = datetime.datetime.now()
           # dat.append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tracker__header"]/div'))).text.splitlines())
            ff.append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[2]/div'))).text.splitlines())
           # ff[len(ff)-1].append(str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second))
            ff[len(ff)-1].append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[2]/div/lbk-scoreboard-details/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span'))).get_attribute("class"))
            ff[len(ff)-1].append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[2]/div/lbk-scoreboard-details/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/span'))).get_attribute("class"))
            print(ff[len(ff)-1])
            print("\n")
            
            if ff[len(ff)-1][2] != "TB":
                y.append(int(ff[len(ff)-1][17][:ff[len(ff)-1][17].find("%")]))
            else:
                y.append(int(ff[len(ff)-1][18][:ff[len(ff)-1][18].find("%")]))
            
            x.append(count)
            
    
            
        except (TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException):
            print('error')
            
        count+=1
        time.sleep(10)
        
        ax1.plot(x,y)
        plt.pause(0.05)
        plt.show()

ani= animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=2000)
```

I am trying to create a real-time graph based on the information that is being retrieved from the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver is running in the main thread and blocking matplotlib from rendering the figure in a window.

You can run the driver is separate thread leaving matplotlib running in the main thread.

The Browser thread can be implemented like so:

```py
from threading import Thread

class Browser(Thread):
    def __init__(self, plot):
        super().__init__()
        self.plot = plot
        self.mkt_board = None

    def run(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://livebetting.sportingbet.com/en/live#/8637814")
        homepage = Homepage(self.driver)
        mkt_board = homepage.marketboard()
        mkt_board.transfer_pulse(self.plot)
```

Here I make sure to have the driver running in the thread by instantiating it in the `run` method.

A `Browser` instance is initialized with a instance of `Plot` declared as:

```py
class Plot:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        style.use('fivethirtyeight')
        x, y = [], []
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax1 = ax1
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ax1.plot(x, y)

    def update(self, x_new, y_new):
        self.x.append(x_new)
        self.y.append(y_new)
        self.ax1.plot(self.x, self.y)
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

    def run(self):
        self.b = Browser(self)
        self.b.start()
        plt.show()
```

Also, I have used the [Page Objects pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) so that it's easier to reason about the flow.

```py
class Page:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def wait_and_find(self, xpath):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        return self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]

class Homepage(Page):
    def scoreboard(self):
        xpath = '//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[2]/div/lbk-scoreboard-common/div/div[1]/a/span'
        return self.wait_and_find(xpath)

    def marketboard(self):
        self.scoreboard().click()
        self.stat().click()
        return Marketboard(self.driver)

    def stat(self):
        xpath = '//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[2]/div/lbk-scoreboard-common/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[1]'
        return self.wait_and_find(xpath)


class Marketboard(Page):
    NO_BETS = 'We are sorry but no bets are available for this event.'

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def wait_and_find(self, xpath):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        return self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)[0]

    def title(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="scoreboard"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[3]')[0].text

    def content(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="event"]/lb-marketboard/div/div/div[1]')[0].text

    def pulse(self, plot):
        '''Replace with info retrieved from your page'''
        while True:
            plot.update(random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100))
            time.sleep(2)
```

Now run the plot.

```py
p = Plot()
p.run()
```