# Matplotlib to view dynamic data

Tags: python, selenium, class, instance

I can currently scrape data by polling an HTML file. I can get data at about 10-15 Hz. I am using selenium and bs4. I can also plot the data using matplotlib but I cannot plot it dynamically. I found the following link and it looks like a good start to multitask scraping and plotting.
[real time graph with matplotlib and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182195/real-time-graph-with-matplotlib-and-selenium)

However, this code is advanced and I am having trouble understanding it. I am not looking for someone to write my code. I am looking to find something similar that uses classes, instances, super(), run, threads etc. that may be over commented or structured for a novice. If the above link shows code for a novice, let me know and I will eventually understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I added a plt.pause(.2) to the code  from matplotlib and it now refreshes from a matrix that is loaded at 10 Hz.